# R: Concatenate two words in a text based on a table

Tags: r, nlp

In R I have an issue with the following:

In a text I want to combine some words (from two to three) that have a specific meaning when together. c("a b", "c d e")

In a text I would like to whenever those two words appear in a given text, I would like to have the same text but when those two words appear together they are bound with a "_".

Exemple : This is an "a" "b" and its beautiful. "c d e" are more expensive.

Would become : This is an "a"_b" and its beautiful. "c_d_e" are more expensive.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried with `paste()` or `paste0()`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `stringr::str_c()` might helps as well

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers I will try with that out. Please excuse me if the answer was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

regex might be a solution for you.
Try the following:

```
library(stringr)
text <-  "This is an \"a b\" and its beautiful. \"c d e\" are more expensive."

str_replace(string = text, pattern = "(?<=a)[:blank:](?=b)", replacement = "_")
[1] "This is an \"a_b\" and its beautiful. \"c d e\" are more expensive."
```

"(?<=a):blank:" this pattern matches all the blank spaces preceded by "a" and followed by "b".

Then you can figure out yourself how to match "c d" and so on ;)

For more go here: https://stringr.tidyverse.org/

Good luck,
L

Comment: Thank you very much